# Hide time row in Kendo UI Scheduler

Tags: javascript, user-interface, time, kendo-ui, scheduler

i took over a Project with the Kendo UI and try to figure out how to remove the Time-Row (http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4027/icax4ca2_png.htm) from the Scheduler.

I read the documentary but i just cant remove it.
Its not the allDaySlot.

It really annoys me, that i cant find the part where to change it. The code looks like this :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        var schedulerSelectState = null;
        var now = new Date();
        
        window.schedulerEinsaetzeDisponiert = $("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
            footer: false,
            date: new Date(),
//            height: 400,
            eventHeight: 30,
            majorTick: 1440,
   
   
            views: [
                {
                    type: "timelineWeek",
                    title: "Wochenansicht"
                },
                {
                    type: "timelineMonth",
                    allDaySlot: false,
                    title: "Monatsansicht",
                    selected: true
                }
            ],
            timezone: "Europe/Berlin",
            selectable: false,
```

Thank you for helping me !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why you do not just use CSS to do it? Like so:

```
#scheduler .k-scheduler-header-wrap .k-scheduler-table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2),
#scheduler .k-scheduler-layout > tbody > tr:first-child > td > .k-scheduler-times .k-scheduler-table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) {
       display: none;
   }
```